# Flutter app is not installed from google play

Tags: flutter, google-play, android-app-bundle

The flutter app runs successfully in release, after uploading on google play when installed on device get the app is not installed.

Comment: It's not running on any device or just the one with release version previously installed?

Comment: Tried 2 devices not work on them

Comment: Have you tried building release apk and install it on those devices? Not just running flutter run release? Just trying to rule out different possibilities. The best way would be to run command `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` try different abi compilations, if they work upload all to Play Store. The store automatically manages which device gets each release later.

Comment: When I tried flutter build apk get the same error

Comment: I think the problem was in build.gradle android:exported was false when make true worked on device will try play store now : <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:exported="true"

Comment: Nice, hope it works now. Always remember to test installation files before release because for whatever reason they work differently than launching app from editor.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was in build.gradle android:exported was false when make true worked on device will try play store now : <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:exported="true"